# Rails same named route but with parameter raises an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As of Rails 4.2, I cannot do the following:

```
  get 'profile', to: 'profile#index', as: 'profile'
  get 'profile/:slug', to: 'profile#show', as: 'profile'
```

because it will raise error saying route is already defined. Why is that? Obviously `profile_path` and `profile_path(User.last.slug)` are not the same, and there should be no difficulty differentiating the two even if they happen to share the same base name (You check if a param is passed).

Thoughts?

Comment: Why not define the "slug" parameter as optional, and then you can merge both? Sure, with some logic in the controller. I think the error you mention has a reason to be, apparently the two actions are for different things, why they have to have the same name?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails, the helper names for different routes should be different. And hence, as you rightly   understood, you will receive an error if you use the same helper name (ie as: 'profile' in your case) for two different routes.

This restriction in Rails helps maintain sanity in your routes.rb file as well as in your application. For instance consider two methods for a controller:

```
class XyzController < ApplicationController
  def method_a(param1)
  end

  def method_b(param1)
  end
end
```

In your routes file if there was no restriction of keeping helper names different, you could have used :

```
get 'xyz/method_a', to: 'profile#method_a', as: 'profile_method'
get 'xyz/method_b', to: 'profile#method_b', as: 'profile_method'
```

Correspondingly in your view file:

```
 link_to 'link_1', profile_method_path('param1')  #intended to route for method_a
 link_to 'link_2', profile_method_path('param2')  #intended to route for method_b
```

As obvious, in the view file, not only is it difficult to make out which route is intended for which method, its also not possible to route to any other controller method using the helper 'profile_method' except the method that is first to use this helper in your routes.rb file (as routes are read sequentially).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I ended up using different named routes.

Answer (score 0):

For both routes you specified `as: 'profile'` and that's your problem here. Besides that, use pluralized route names for `#index` action, e.g:

```
get 'profiles', to: 'profile#index'
```